# Shell script needs to open images for viewing/previewing

Tags: applescript, command-line, preview

I have a shell script that is going to open two images and then use "&" to return focus to the script. qlmanage is not suitable for sever reasons, but the biggest problem is the inability to specify where it will open... it seems to always open in the middle of the display (meaning one image will cover the other). It seems unscriptable, if there is a way via osascript to move it after opening, I have not discovered it.

Preview.app is hardly better in this regard.

I need to position the two images side-by-side, as if they were pages of a book. Is there a built-in image viewer for MacOS that is suitable? Is there an image viewer/previewer I can download for this purpose? Can either of Firefox or Chrome be abused towards these ends (images are browser loadable, either jpg or png)?

Ideally, I could specify where the windows load from the command line, but any way to config that which is persistent through many loads of images will work. As a last resort, if the windows are apple-scriptable so that the shell script can move them after opening, that won't be intolerable.

Comment: A window with a couple of views can be created via the Cocoa API (AppleScriptObjC, JXA, helper app, etc), how is the shell script going to interact with the viewer?

Comment: The shell script needs to be able to open arbitrary image files, and the image viewer either needs enough sense to not open on top of the terminal window, or to be movable after the fact. No other interaction is necessary. The shell script is opening a file editor (with the OCRed contents of the image, for tweaks), and when the editor closes, the shell script should be able to shut down the viewer (was just doing 'killall qlmanage' for that). It's on a loop, so it will open more images, another file editor, etc, until through the whole batch.

Comment: In applescript, you could always do something like this: set bounds of window 1 to {4, 24, 688, 872}; set bounds of window 2 to {696, 24, 1380, 872}; (replace ; with linefeed). Try it with preview and two open images.